# PyRPlidar IndexError: index out of range

Tags: python, lidar

Running the example code in the pyrplidar documentation

```
from pyrplidar import PyRPlidar

lidar = PyRPlidar()
lidar.connect(port="COM8", baudrate=256000, timeout=3)
# Linux   : "/dev/ttyUSB0"
# MacOS   : "/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART"
# Windows : "COM5"


info = lidar.get_info()
print("info :", info)

health = lidar.get_health()
print("health :", health)

samplerate = lidar.get_samplerate()
print("samplerate :", samplerate)


scan_modes = lidar.get_scan_modes()
print("scan modes :")
for scan_mode in scan_modes:
    print(scan_mode)


lidar.disconnect()
```

give this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\RPlidar\test1.py", line 10, in <module>
    info = lidar.get_info()
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyrplidar.py", line 73, in get_info
    discriptor = self.receive_discriptor()
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyrplidar.py", line 42, in receive_discriptor
    discriptor = PyRPlidarResponse(self.lidar_serial.receive_data(RPLIDAR_DESCRIPTOR_LEN))
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyrplidar_protocol.py", line 110, in __init__
    self.sync_byte1 = raw_bytes[0]
IndexError: index out of range
```

How do I solve this? Please help

Comment: Could be a bad port setup, a bad connection or a bug in the library.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't think its the port setup or the connection. Last updated of the library was on Jul 26, 2019

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What works is installing the rplidar library or adafruit_rplidar library. Both work.

Installing rp lidar library:

```
pip install rplidar
```

Info link to library:
https://pypi.org/project/rplidar/

Installing adafruit library:

```
pip install Adafruit_CircuitPython_RPLIDAR
```

Info link to library:
https://pypi.org/project/adafruit-circuitpython-rplidar/

There are also some other solves and infos about that (like changing some atribute in pyrplidar_serial.py, see here: https://github.com/Hyun-je/pyrplidar/issues/1) but they didn't work for me.
There is some discussion about broken firmware and also some possible solution which I didn't try (see here: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_RPLIDAR/issues/15)